# Increase entropy_avail on Cavium

Tags: random

The device is Octeon by Cavium which contains a RNG hardware unit. OS show Current entropy pool size is 4096 bytes but entropy_avail is very low.The device crypto modules has ansi_cprng.ko present only, no other RNG related .ko present, additionally as per lsmod no RNG related modules loaded. However, the kernel config settings related to RNG are as following;
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ANSI_CPRNG=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_HW=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG2=y

How to feed /dev/random from Octeon RNG and increase entropy_avail, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `cavium_rng` module (enabled with `CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_CAVIUM`).

However, this is off-topic.

This is a question about Linux, not about cryptography, so the Unix StackExchange website would have been a better fit for it.